# Question about Visual Studio 2010's built in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hey guys, 
I was wondering when you create a new website project in ASP.NET and it comes with that login and register page by default, do people actually use these basic pages for a website?  More specifically, is it very common to use the login controls and the CreateUserWizard?  Are these controls the basis of any user account login?  I want to learn it, but i feel like if most people don't even use it then there's no point for me to learn these controls and how they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those controls are enough customizable to be used in a common web application. I often use them because they already use asp.net membership.

But, if they don't fit your needs, you can do your own controls.

Answer (score 0):

What comes with a new MVC project is just a very basic page to show you how the different layers of MVC work together and to give you an idea about best-practice.

A lot of people use this as a start for a new project. If you start learning MVC you should first understand how this basic MVC project and its controls works and then move on to more advanced technics.